# How to disable autoindent on enter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see multiple settings for Code in terms of *how* to indent (spaces vs tabs), but nothing about how to disable indents. So for example, I enter a `<p>` tag, hit enter, and Code auto indents the next line. I'd like to disable that but cannot find the setting to do so.

Comment: Not sure, but it might be `"editor.formatOnType"` that would be set to `true`? It should be `false` by default though.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option to disable auto indent on enter. But if you need to insure that inline elements remain without extra spaces because it affects the layout you can use the new option, [introduced in v1.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates#_languages-html): `html.format.unformatted` - comma separated list of tags that shouldn't be reformatted. Default value `null` means that all [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements) should remain as you formatted them.

In addition, instead of typing `<p>` + Enter you can type just `p` and press tab which will give you a nice `<p><\p>` and will place the cursor in the middle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: A(/The?) feature request is here btw.: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5446 They didn't bother to add this feature in the past three years, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set the configuration property `editor.autoIndent` in your `settings.json` file (which for me was in `C:\Users\$USER\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`). the value you want to set it to is the string `"none"`.

see this thread for more details https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5446#issuecomment-559145939